# Elysium style destroyed when using WindowsFormsHost

Tags: wpf, windowsformshost

I'm using Elysium in my wpf application to get a metro styled interface. However the style is not preserved when I try to use Windows forms control.

Example:

```
<Grid>
    <RichTextBox />
</Grid>
```

Gives a perfect result (with the thin white border around the wpf control)

However:

```
 xmlns:WinForms="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms"
 .
 .   
<Grid>
    <WindowsFormsHost  Name="wfh">
        <WinForms:RichTextBox />
    </WindowsFormsHost>
</Grid>
```

Gives me a different look with the legacy windows form type of border.

I want the thin white border around my WindowsFormElement if possible. I'm out of ideas at the moment.

Comment: Not sure what you're expecting. The first example you give uses WPF's `RichTextBox`, whereas the second is using Winform's `RichTextBox`, which are completely different controls. AFAIK, Elysium is a set of styles for WPF, not Winforms.

Comment: OK maybe its as simple as that. I was expecting the thin white border around the windowsformshost element.